# Optimizing a custom ranking function in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I have my own desired functional form for a function that takes as input a series of features (some are integers, some are continuous), and I'd like to optimize the coefficients that multiply these features such that the samples that I consider acceptable rank first.

In other words, given a supplied functional form, I want to fit the coefficients to spit out a real number that can be used to rank my samples. The more cases that when scored with this function rank my desired samples #1, the better the coefficients.

It's important for me to be able to see the value of these coefficients, with my given functional form, at the end of my fitting.

This doesn't quite seem to fall into SVM or logistic regressions (although I could be mistaken).

Is there an existing package that offers this?

---

### Here is a more concrete example

Imagine I have software which makes predictions regarding the shape of some 3D blob. Say I have 5 predictions and I'd like to know which one is the most likely to be correct. To do this, I'd like to construct a scoring function. The function will weight differently the three features from each of the models.

Let's call these features:

1. Surface Area -- call it 'A'
2. Volume -- call it 'V'
3. Number of channels that pass through the blob -- call it 'C' (notice this is an integer)

Now I know roughly how I want these features to interact. For example, I think a blob with one channel is very different from a blob with no channels. But a blob with 10 channels is not very different from a blob with 9 channels.

So I'm going to set up a functional form that includes a step function for the number of channels.

I also want the surface area and volume to be relative values compared to each of the other 5 predictions made. And I want these features to have a linear term and a quadratic term.

So the functional form is something like:

```
score(A,V,H) = w1*a + w2*a^2 + w3*v * w3*v^2 + STEP_FUNCTION_FOR_NUM_CHANNELS_WITH_THREE_STEPS_SO_NEED_THREE_WEIGHTS
```

I also have a training set. It consists of, say, 100 different kinds of blobs, and for each kind of blob, I have 5 predictions and I know which of the 5 predictions I want to rank #1.

So what I have then is a functional form that I like and a classification for each of the predictions.

I'm looking for an existing package which can optimize the coefficients ( the `w's` ) such that the desired prediction in each of the 100 different kinds of blobs is ranked #1 as often as possible.

Comment: Any chance you can create an example and share your custom function? When I read your question, my mind thinks scipy optimize or custom scikit-learn [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

Comment: The make_scorer function seems to be for the development of a loss function for cross-validation purposes. It seems every example I find, it's used for hyper-parameter optimization. Like evaluating the performance of different SVMs where the 'C' parameter is varied.

Comment: The scipy optimize function doesn't quite seem to fit my purposes. What I want to optimize is the number of cases which are correctly ranked, so my function would return an integer. Sci-py optimize seems to require the function return a float.